# bind event on a group instead separately

Tags: jquery, performance

According to performance which is faster

```
    <div class="pull-left btn-group">
        <a href="#" id="PrintInDocument"></a>
        <a href="#" id="EditDocument"></a>
        <a href="#" id="DivideDocument"</a>
        <a href="#" id="DeleteInDoc"</a>
        <a href="#" id="ChangeDocStatus"</a>
    </div>

$(document).on("click", "#InDocumentResultsTable div.btn-group a", function () {
    //some code
    if (this.id == "EditDocument") {
        ...
    } else if(this.id == "PrintInDocument") {
        ...
    }
});
```

or binding each separately like:

```
$(document).on("click", "#PrintInDocument", function () {  //some code });

$(document).on("click", "#EditDocument", function () {  //some code });
```

What if the html  tags do not have an id attribute (and, for example, each of them have an individual class)?

Comment: it is considered rude to vote down without an explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> According to performance which is faster

**It doesn't matter**. Click events are human-generated, and so they're judged by human timescales, not computer timescales. You're never going to have a DOM structure so deep that there's a perceptible delay clicking on its deepest section but handling the click at the document level.

There are several reasons to choose delegation over direct handling and vice-versa, but performance is almost never one of them. Simplicity in terms of adding/removing elements (favors delegation), better control over bubbling (favors direct handling), and so on, yes; but not performance.

But:

**In theory**, by handling the click at the document level, you're running code (inside jQuery) every time there's a click anywhere on the document so that jQuery can figure out whether to run a delegated handler for that click. That's running code you could have avoided if the click isn't relevant to any delegated handler.

Countering that argument is that attaching separate handlers to individual elements uses more memory than attaching a single handler, and takes longer to hook up. But you'd probably have to be in the hundreds of thousands of elements for that to matter.

But again: From a performance perspective, it's not going to matter.